# Нужно сделать голосование для фотографии с непонятной мне концепцией

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно разместить в документе в вертикальный ряд несколько фотографии. Каждой фотографии сопоставить ссылки + и - имитируя голосования за нее. Сбоку от фотографии отображать прямоугольник, длина которого должна быть пропорциональна поданному за фотографию кол-ву голосов (справа - для положительного рейтинга, слева - для отрицательного)

Помогите пожалуйста((

Не очень понимаю, как сделать такое голосование

Answer (score 2):

Для понимания концепции:

```js
document.querySelector('.set').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  let target = ev.target;
  if (target.tagName !== 'BUTTON') return;
  let meter = target.closest('.rate').querySelector('.meter');
  let voteUp = parseInt(meter.dataset.up) || 0;
  let voteDown = parseInt(meter.dataset.down) || 0;
  if (target.classList.contains('up')) {
    meter.dataset.up = ++voteUp;
  } else {
    meter.dataset.down = ++voteDown;
  }
  meter.textContent = `${voteUp} • ${voteDown}`;
  meter.style.setProperty('--vote', `${(voteUp / (voteUp + voteDown)) * 100}%`);
});
```

```css
.set {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  gap: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 1em;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 45%;
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.rate {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1em;
  width: 45%;
}

.meter {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#090 0 0), linear-gradient(#e91b0c 0 0);
  background-position: left 50%, right 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: calc(var(--vote, 50%)) 100%, calc(100% - var(--vote, 50%)) 100%;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #ccc;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.meter:not([data-up]):not([data-down]) { background-size: 0 0; }

.votes {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
}

.votes > button {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  font: 28px/1em monospace;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px #0008, 0 0 1px 1px #0008;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.votes > button:hover::before { mix-blend-mode: color-burn; }
.up::before { content: '\1F44D'; color: #090; }
.down::before { content: '\1F44E'; color: #e91b0c;
}
```

```html
<div class="set">

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MraLT.jpg" alt="red wall">
    <div class="rate">
      <div class="meter">0</div>
      <div class="votes">
        <button class="up"></button>
        <button class="down"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxVNC.jpg" alt="yellow flower">
    <div class="rate">
      <div class="meter">0</div>
      <div class="votes">
        <button class="up"></button>
        <button class="down"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9VLC.jpg" alt="green forest">
    <div class="rate">
      <div class="meter">0</div>
      <div class="votes">
        <button class="up"></button>
        <button class="down"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYG0R.jpg" alt="blue rose">
    <div class="rate">
      <div class="meter">0</div>
      <div class="votes">
        <button class="up"></button>
        <button class="down"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```